# I'd like to know what this property is called?

Tags: notation, terminology, partial-derivative

Suppose I have a function $f(x,y)$ such that it's partial derivatives are equal.  In other words,

$$\frac{\partial} {\partial x}f = \frac{\partial} {\partial y}f.$$

What is the name for this property?

Comment: Can you type in MathJax the function and its partial derivatives ?

Comment: The partial derivates for $ x $ and $y$ are not the same !

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking something like, "If $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f$, then what is the name of this property?"

Comment: Yes, that's is exactly my question @KevinFlowersJr

Comment: @Fred Maybe I didn't express myself correctly. I mean exactly the expression Kevin writed.

Comment: @renton01, ah gotcha.   I updated your question to reflect that & removed the previous equation since it wasn't an example of a case where $\frac{\partial} {\partial x}f = \frac{\partial} {\partial y}f$.

Comment: Not an answer to your question "what is this property called," but it looks like a function that satisfies that property is equal to a function over one variable https://math.stackexchange.com/a/495404/570998